# Closed form of $\int_0^2\frac{1}{2+\sqrt{3\,e^x+3\,e^{-x}-2}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, exponential-function, closed-form

Could you please help me to solve this integration problem?
$$\int_0^2\frac{1}{2+\sqrt{3\,e^x+3\,e^{-x}-2}}dx$$
Its approximate numeric value is [$0.419197813818367...$](http://tinyurl.com/0419197813818367), but I could not find an exact symbolic expression for it.

Comment: What leads you to believe it even has a closed form? :)

Comment: @experimentX When I give this integral as a direct input to _Mathematica_, it returns unevaluated. Did you perform any transformations before feeding it to _Mathematica_?

Comment: One thing you could try is to pull one factor of $e^{-x}$ out of the square root and then treat the remaining parts as a quadratic.

Comment: @MartyColos $3 e^{x} + 3 e^{-x} = 6 \cosh(x)$

Comment: When I changed the variable $y=e^x$ and fed the transformed integral $\displaystyle\int_1^{e^2}\frac{dy}{y\,\left(2+\sqrt{3\,y+\frac{3}{y}-2}\right)}$ to _Mathematica_, it returned a huge result involving incomplete elliptic functions with complex arguments, that seems to agree with the numerical integration. I will try to simplify it.

Comment: *Mathematica* gives 

$ \int f(x)dx  = \int \frac{dx}{2+\sqrt{6\cosh x-2}}  
= I(x) = (1/6) \left[(2 - \sqrt{-2 + 6 \cosh x}~)\cdot \coth \frac{x}{2} - 
   2~ i~ E_2((i~ x/2),~ 3) - 4~i ~E_1((i~x/2),~ 3)\right]. $ Using Santosh Linkha's idea, and taking care to take the $\lim_{a\to 0} \int_a^2$ gives the answer in the OP. $E_1,E_2$ are elliptic integrals.

Comment: May relate to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2043030

Answer (score 1):

$\int_0^2\dfrac{1}{2+\sqrt{3e^x+3e^{-x}-2}}dx$

$=\int_1^{e^2}\dfrac{1}{2+\sqrt{3y+\dfrac{3}{y}-2}}d(\ln y)$

$=\int_1^{e^2}\dfrac{1}{y\left(2+\sqrt{3y+\dfrac{3}{y}-2}\right)}dy$

$=\int_1^{e^2}\dfrac{1}{2y+y\sqrt{3y+\dfrac{3}{y}-2}}dy$

$=\int_1^{e^2}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3y^3-2y^2+3y}+2y}dy$

$=\int_1^{e^2}\dfrac{\sqrt{3y^3-2y^2+3y}-2y}{\left(\sqrt{3y^3-2y^2+3y}+2y\right)\left(\sqrt{3y^3-2y^2+3y}-2y\right)}dy$

$=\int_1^{e^2}\dfrac{\sqrt{3y^3-2y^2+3y}-2y}{3y^3-2y^2+3y-4y^2}dy$

$=\int_1^{e^2}\dfrac{\sqrt{3y^3-2y^2+3y}}{3y^3-6y^2+3y}dy-\int_1^{e^2}\dfrac{2y}{3y^3-6y^2+3y}dy$

$=\int_1^{e^2}\dfrac{\sqrt{3y^3-2y^2+3y}}{3y(y-1)^2}dy-\int_1^{e^2}\dfrac{2}{3(y-1)^2}dy$

which can express in terms of [Lauricella Functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lauricella_hypergeometric_series#Integral_representation_of_FD)